# How to refresh my table on a time-out function of 3 seconds

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having difficulty with refreshing only my table in my index page of the mvc5 application on a time-out of 5 seconds. I have read quite a few posts about it here but my understanding is very basic.

I have an ActionResult called Index that returns a stored procedure to populate a dropdown list when I select a value and submit it I have another controller called Index but it has [HttpPost] above it, this now saves the selected value of the dropdown passes it to another stored proc and returns a model to the view to create a table. I want to refresh this table on a time out of 5 seconds. I have tried to first refresh with a button using the following below.

```
<tbody id="refresh"> <!--The Id I use for my table -->
<input id="butt" type="submit" value="Go" /> <!--The button to refresh-->

<script>
    $("#butt").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Index',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#refresh").html(data);
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Here is my controller:

```
DBEntities  db = new DBEntites();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    CircuitClass model = new CircuitClass();

    model.MyCircuit = db.GetAllCircuits(DateTime.Today);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(CircuitClass model)
{
    string circuit = model.SelectedCircuit.ToString();
    int raceNo = model.SelectedRaceNo;
    if (model.SelectedRaceNo == 0 || (model.SelectedCircuit == null))
    {
      return View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml");
    }
    else
        model.MyResults = db.GetCircuitResults(circuit, raceNo, DateTime.Today).ToList();
    model.MyCircuit = db.GetAllCircuits(DateTime.Today);

    return View(model);
}
```

In debug, I press the button which takes me to the Index controller that doesn't have [HttpPost] above it which is where I need to refresh the table. I was expecting it to load the controller with [HttpPost]. 
My approach may be completely wrong, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setInterval` function from  js to call `display` function every 5 seconds

```
$("#butt").on('click', display());

function display()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Index',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#refresh").html(data);
        }
    })
}

setInterval(function(){ display(); }, 5000); //Refreshes every 5 sec
```

(Or) `trigger` the button click every 5 sec

```
$("#butt").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Index',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#refresh").html(data);
        }
    })
})

setInterval(function(){  $("#butt").trigger('click') }, 5000);
```

Comment: Hi Deepak, Thank you for your response, I would like it to be without a button if possible, I was trying with a button to learn how it works - my goal is to have it refresh on a timer alone. Also, the big issue is the controller part of my question, how do i have it go to the index controller with [HttpPost] above it? Thank you

Comment: Add `[HttpPost]` data annotation above given method in given controller and add `method: post` to your [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-examples) call. @KidKoder

Comment: @Barrosy Thank you for the response, putting the method: post, it worked.